# Airflow BashOperator output not being logged after upgrade to v1.10

Tags: airflow

I finally upgraded Airflow from v1.8 to v1.10. We heavily use the BashOperator to run scripts that produce a lot of output (progress status, actions, error reporting) that would appear in the task logs that get saved to S3.

After the upgrade, this is not happening anymore. Log files are being created, but the scripts' output isn't being logged. When an error happens, there will be an airflow error logged; something along the lines of 'bash command failed'. The error messages produced by the script aren't there.

Is output handled differently that I'm not seeing in the docs? Is there a setting change from v1.8 to v1.10 that I may have missed? Or something else that I should be looking at?

Here are some of the logging settings that are active:

```
logging_level = WARN
remote_logging = TRUE
remote_base_log_folder = s3://xxxxxx-import-logs
remote_log_conn_id = xxxxxx_s3_conn
encrypt_s3_logs = False
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I changed the logging level to INFO and now the output is being logged as it was before the upgrade.